# Learning to use xparse

Tags: macros, xparse

I'm learning to use `xparse` to build commands with optional arguments. But I'm having problems:

I want to make a command called `\topcat` with output:

```
\mathcal{O} if no argument is specified 
\mathcal{O}^{#1} if we specify \topcat[op]
```

I tried to use something like:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\topcatm}{o}{#1}{$\mathcal{O}$^{\IfValueTF{#1}}}
```

It'd be great if someone could give me some tips for `xparse` I tried to read about `xparse` in CTAN but I find it quite dense.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`xparse` can be a little bit confusing on the first glance, since it has a different syntax compared to `\newcommand`.

The syntax is

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\macroname}{argument specifiers}{%
expansion code
}
```

The argument specifiers are quite useful. If an optional argument is requested and there is no default value given, then `o` is most likely the right choice, otherwise use `O{default}` (replace default with the default value ;-))

Now, if `o` is used, the command `\IfValueTF` or `\IfValueT` or `\IfValueF` decides, whether the optional argument is given at all. (Which one is to be applied depends on the specific needs. If unsure, use `\IfValueTF`. )

(If none of the mentioned `\IfValueTF` macros is used, the replacement 'text' of the relevant argument is `-NoValue-` if the optional argument was specified to be of `o` type and was omitted in the macro call)

The usage is

```
\IfValueTF{#1}{true code}{false code}
```

Althought the trial code by the O.P. might work concerning the `^{\IfValueTF{#1}...}` I don't recommend this syntax, just for clarity reasons.

Here's a working version, however, I removed the `$...$` characters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}


\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\topcatm}{o}{%
  \IfValueTF{#1}{%
    \mathcal{O}^{#1}%
  }{%
    \mathcal{O}%
  }%
}
\begin{document}

$ \topcatm$ 


$\topcatm[foo]$
\end{document}
```

[image]

`xparse` provides the facility to use different `delimiters` such as `<>` or `()` for optional arguments, using the `d` or `D` specifiers instead of `o` or `O`

Comment: I restrict my explanations to the absolutely necessary case. The same explanations are true for `\DeclareDocumentCommand` and `\RenewDocumentCommand` etc.

Comment: Crystal clear explanation I needed something like this :)

Comment: @Abellan: You're welcome! Happy TeXing!

Comment: Nice answer, but the code can be reduced to `\mathcal{O}\IfValueT{#1}{^{#1}}`, which is quite interesting as well, because it explains the usage of `\IfValue(TF)`.

Comment: @egreg: I know, but I am not really a fan of such constructs actually.

Comment: I forgot it! I'm very sorry. Yes of course I was extremely useful!